# How to find browser user-agent with selenium in ruby

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, cucumber, selenium-webdriver

I want to know current user-agent. I have used selenium2 with ruby

I have set user-agent in env.rb

```
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|

  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile['general.useragent.override'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7"

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :firefox, :profile =>  profile})
end
```

And when run cucumber test cases opened `FireFox Browser` and I does not see iphone. SO I want to check test cases is running in with iphone mode(user-agent). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check your browser is open in Iphone mode so you visit "http://google.com" from your test cases and you will see web page is opened with mobile mode. So you can justify you have set proper user-agent.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ irb
2.3.3 :001 > require 'selenium-webdriver'
 => true 
2.3.3 :002 > d = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome)
 => #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x..fcc762e239318ca30 browser=:chrome> 
2.3.3 :003 > d.execute_script('return navigator.userAgent')
 => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36" 
2.3.3 :004 > d.quit
 => nil 
2.3.3 :005 >
$
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this:-

```
page.driver.browser.browser

=> 

:firefox
```